# Folder access issue in window7 with out administrator rights

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, windows-7, windows-services

I want to access folder where i can read write and delete files in C drive through my application and application is developed in asp.net using c# which is window service.
I found `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming` or `C:\Program Data` folder which is accessible for all user and where he can read write or delete files with out admin rights.
But unfortunately this is not available in window xp
Is there any folder available in xp and win7 where user can write/delete/read with out administrator rights?

Comment: You need to test what ever you do on IIS. The application pool identity will need to be give permission to write/delete files in a temp directory. Additionally, the server does not have a user profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the temporary folder on the C drive: "C:\Temp".

Comment: I don't have a "C:\Temp" folder. I recommend using [`Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) instead.

Comment: +1 I used to have a Temp-folder back in my XP-days, also now on Win 7, I have one. But your solution is nicer. :)

Comment: You need to test this on IIS. The application pool identity will need to be give permission to write/delete files in a temp directory. Additionally, the server does not have a user profile.

Comment: You should never do this. Regular users do not have read/write permission to folders at the root level of the disk, nor *should* they.